# Iterating through a list of names and printing it out with an index (with a dot)

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, count

Please help me understand this as I am new to python:

I have a list of names...

```
names = ['John', 'William', 'Amanda']
```

I need to iterate through this list and print out the names as follows:

```
1. John
2. William
3. Amanda
```

I've managed to print the list out however I'm getting this extra space between the index number and the dot like this:

```
1' '. John

2' '. William

3' '. Amanda
```

my code:

```
index = 1
for i in names:

    print(index, '.', i)
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most pythonic way of doing this in Python 3 is using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```py
names = ['John', 'William', 'Amanda']

for index, item in enumerate(names, start=1):
    print(f'{index}. {item}')
```

Output:

```
1. John
2. William
3. Amanda
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of easy ways by which you can achieve this:

1. `enumerate` and `f-string`:

```
for index,item in enumerate(names,start=1):
    print(f'{index}. {item}')
```

2. `enumerate` and `format function`:

```
for index,item in enumerate(names,start=1):
    print('{}. {}'.format(index,item))
```

3. `enumerate` and `string formating`:

```
for index,item in enumerate(names,start=1):
    print('%s. %s' %(index,item))
```

4. `enumerate` and manipulating args of `print` function:

```
for index,item in enumerate(names,start=1):
    print(index,'. ',item, sep='')
```

5. With `range`:

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    print((i+1),'. ',names[i], sep='')
```

6. with range and `f-string`:

```
for i in range(len(names)):
    print(f'{(i+1)}. {names[i]}')
```

7. using `extra variable` (Not recommended):

```
index = 1
names = ['John', 'William', 'Amanda']

for i in names: 
  print(index, '. ', i, sep='')
  index += 1
```

NOTE: There are various other ways to do this. But, I'll recommend using `enumerate` with `f-string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separator using the `sep` option in `print`

Like this

```
index = 1
names = ['John', 'William', 'Amanda']

for i in names: 
  print(index, '.' ,' ', i, sep='') #If you dont want the space between the '.' and i you may remove it
  index += 1

#OUTPUT:
#1. John
#2. William
#3. Amanda
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a space after your dote, and you don't really need the index variable. I changed your code a little bit:

**Code:**

```
names = ['John', 'William', 'Amanda']

for i in range(len(names)):
    index = str(i + 1)
    print(index + '. ' + names[i]) 
    # if you don't want the space beween the dot and the name change '. ' to '.'
```

**Output:**

```
1. John
2. William
3. Amanda
```

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['John', 'William', 'Amanda']
counter = 1

for name in names:
    print(str(counter) + ". " + name)
    counter += 1
```

This is what you were trying to do. Your mistake is that you're using the wrong concatenation symbol (need to use +)

[result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2fDi.png)